# Can every DFA be simulated by a PDA?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, pushdown-automata, simulation

Given a Deterministic Finite Automata (DFA) $M_1$, does there always exist a Pushdown Automata (PDA) $M_2$ that accepts the same language as $M_1$?  I.e. **can any DFA be simulated by a PDA?**  Intuitively, it makes sense to me that a PDA is more powerful since it has an arbitrary amount of memory and can therefore accept more languages than a DFA, but how could this be formally proven?

Comment: What happens when you take PDA and ignore stack (not use it)?

Comment: @Evil In that case, it's just a DFA (or an NFA?).  Would this be sufficient proof?

Comment: It wouldn't be a *formal* proof, but it's easy to get there from the idea.

Comment: It is rather a concept, something that directly and intuitively maps problem, but as proof it is not even hand waving yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this answer will help you to understand the mapping. Any DFA is also a PDA. The state transitions in the DFA are similar for PDA without stack. For every transition you perform in DFA, make the similar transition in PDA and do not push/pull from stack.

**For a transition**

In DFA : $\delta(q_x,0) \rightarrow q_y$

In stack : $\delta(q_x,0) \rightarrow (q_y,\epsilon)$

**For accepting state**

In DFA : $\delta(q_x,0) \rightarrow q_f$

In stack : $\delta(q_x,0) \rightarrow (q_f,\epsilon)$

Comment: Of course there *is* a formal proof, and what you write here is the first part of it. The other part is showing that the two machines behave exactly the same on any input.

Comment: Thankyou @RanG. for poitning out the mistake. I edited the answer.

Comment: what about NFAs? Can every NFA be simulated by a PDA?

Comment: @x89 Sure, every NFA can be converted to a DFA so every NFA can be simulated by a PDA